# Compile Link LUA5.1 Lib. Error in dev-cpp

Tags: lua, dev-c++

this is my dev-cpp compiler log:

```
rm -f main.o  luaTest.exe'

gcc.exe -c main.c -o main.o -I"E:/Dev-Cpp/include"  -I"E:/Lua/5.1/include"'   
gcc.exe main.o  -o "luaTest.exe" -L"E:/Dev-Cpp/lib" -L "E:/lua/5.1/lua5.1.lib"'  

main.o(.text+0x34):main.c: undefined reference to 'luaL_newstate'

main.o(.text+0x48):main.c: undefined reference to 'luaL_openlibs'

main.o(.text+0xab):main.c: undefined reference to 'luaL_loadbuffer'

main.o(.text+0xd5):main.c: undefined reference to 'lua_pcall'

main.o(.text+0x11c):main.c: undefined reference to 'lua_tolstring'

main.o(.text+0x14e):main.c: undefined reference to 'lua_settop'

main.o(.text+0x161):main.c: undefined reference to 'lua_close'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status'

make.exe: *** [luaTest.exe] Error 1'
```

I can compiling & linking my code success with code::blocks. I can't figure out what's wrong with dev-cpp.

Comment: Why do you insist on using dev-cpp? It is a horribly outdated/neglected tool. As you have already discovered, Code::Blocks is infinitely superior. Drop dev-cpp right now. :]

Comment: I couldn't agree more. It's even in the information of the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out what's wrong with dev-cpp.when you want to link lib file you must shut down the makefile generation in the compiler option

Answer (score 0):

The linking step looks off. The option `-L` (uppercase L) sets a search directory for libs referenced via `-l` (lowercase L). The last step tries to link to `lua5.1.lib` using `-L` instead of the correct `-l`.

Comment: I have found out what's wrong with dev-cpp.when you want to link lib file you must shut down the makefile generation in the compiler option.BTY -L is OK,But there must be one -L.